# UIScrollView with Paging Enabled with separate .xibs?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xib, uipagecontrol

I want to create a UIScrollView with Paging Enabled, however, I want to have three pages.  Each page would be a separate Xib, though.  Is this possible?

Also, is it possible to have have separate .h and .m files for each page, or is that just asking too much?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for you first question - try to check out that link:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html
for your second question - if your mean to different names,i think that really making mass and doesnt necessary, but anyway, the file's name doesnt really matter, just #import the right .h file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though when I run the project source code on the simulator, it's buggy and does weird things... It only works when swiping backwards through the pages.  I'll try it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168

It has multiple view controllers, and you have to convert your project to use storyboard, but it works great!